# C# error: operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Tags: c#, string, char, operators

Today, following a tutorial from a book (literally) I got an unexpected error:

```
operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'
```

in this part of code:

```
public void displayFullName()
{
    StringBuilder FullName = new StringBuilder();

    FullName.Append(firstName);
    FullName.Append(" ");
    if (middleName[0] != "") //ERROR occurs here
    {
        FullName.Append(middleName[0]);
        FullName.Append(". ");
    }
    FullName.Append(lastName);

    Console.WriteLine(FullName);
}
```

where of course middleName is declared as:

```
    class Person
{
    private string firstName;
    private string middleName; //obiously declared as string
    private string lastName;
    private int age;
(...the rest of code...)
```

So, the question is how would you resolve this error?

Comment: What is the name and author of this book?

Comment: @Virtlink It's and old book, ISBN: 0-672-32071-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `middleName` is a `string`, `middleName[0]` is not: it is a single character from the `middleName`, its initial one. You cannot compare it to an empty string, but you can compare the entire middle name, like this:

```
if (middleName != "")
```

A better way to see if a string is empty is to use the [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method of `System.String` for it:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
```

Comment: Thank you - my fina lsolution was that:

if (middleName != "")

Comment: Actually this if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName)) should be like this: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))

Answer (score 10):

> So, the question is how would you resolve this error?

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. Let's look at the line in question:

```
if (middleName[0] != "")
```

What are you really trying to determine here? It makes no sense to ask whether the first character of `middleName` (which is what `middleName[0]` returns) is an empty string. If you'd been checking whether it equals "X" (or some other single-character string) then I might have thought you wanted `if (middleName.StartsWith(...))`.

But if you're *actually* just trying to find out if `middleName` is not empty, you can use:

```
if (middleName != "")
```

or if `middleName` could also be null and you want to detect that, you might want:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
```

In fact, if `middleName` is empty, then `middleName[0]` would throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

As a side-issue - unless this is really a one-off, it suggests you should find a different book. While mistakes can slip through, you really, really should be able to expect code in a book to compile (unless it's trying to demonstrate a failure). You might want to edit your question to name and shame the book in question :) (The fact that it's using a method name of `displayFullName` and a variable name of `FullName` in C# is also somewhat damning.)

Comment: Actually if you look carefully to code you can see that author try to determine if middleName is NOT empty, so this 
if (middleName == "") might not be good but this is good: (middleName != "") 

Anyway, thank you for detailed analysis.

Comment: The book is [Teach yourself C# in 21 days](http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-21-Days/dp/0672320711) by Bradley L. Jones.

Comment: @nenad: If Virtlink is right and it's that book, you should find a more recent book - one which *at least* covers C# 3. (Covering C# 4 and C# 5 would be good too, but C# without LINQ and lambda expressions is icky...)

Comment: I agree, it's just that I found this second-hand book for almost free at university campus. And I like Sams series of books 'cause I learned Java from one of it. Also, chapters in this book, and chapters in JAVA course I took at university are almost completely identical, covering also VERY similar examples. I bought much more recent C# book as well, but I'll read it later. I also noticed you published book as well - I might consider it buying as well, once when I'm done with these books. Anyway, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

with middleName[0] you are getting the first character of that string, therefore, a char.

If you want to compare the first character of the string then use:

```
middleName[0] != ''
```

If you want to compare the full string then:

```
middleName != ""
```

Comment: `''` isn't a valid character literal. A character literal has to be a *single character*.

Comment: Your suggestion guided me to right direction. Thanks.
However this won't work: middleName[0] != '' 
Error is "Empty character literal"

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this:

```
if (middleName[0] != ' ')
{
    FullName.Append(middleName[0]);
    FullName.Append(". ");
}
```

Or even better (assuming this is what the code is meant to do):

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(middleName))
{
    FullName.Append(middleName[0]);
    FullName.Append(". ");
}
```

The problem is the code was trying to compare a `char` to a `string`

`middleName[0]` is of type `char`

`""` is of type `string`

Comment: You are right, this works:

if (middleName[0] != ' ')

and the other solution as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

middleName is declared as string, that's true. But string consists of chars. You are trying to access the first element of the string, which is char.
So simply change it to

```
middleName != ""
```

or

```
middleName[0] != 'a'
```

if you want to check the first character only

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a char(which is always something, any symbol and cannot be empty) with an empty string(which contains no chars).
Use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) instead:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName[0]))
```

if you want to check your middleName against being empty

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it is error in code in the book,

Anyway, when I changed it to:

```
if( middleName != "" )
```

code works flawlessly.

Alternatively, for additional check if the middleName is NULL (if previous program logic skipped to check that) solution to this could be:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName))
```